# UINavigation Controller and UITabbarController connumdrum

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have searched and searched but as yet still cannot figure this ole problem out! :-(

I have in my *main.xib* a *TabBarController* that is setup with five *viewControllers*.

I am trying to get the first viewcontroller to be a nav controller so that if the first tab is selected I can push and pop views into view.

But for the life of me I cannot get this to work?

I tried this in my app delegate didLaunch method:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate=self;
FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *firstNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:first];  
NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNav, nil];  
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;  
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

for which I see my view displayed but no buttons appear on the tab bar?

Any tip please??  thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you have to add View Controllers in TabBar programatically. Like below:

```
oFirstViewController.title = @"First View";
oFirstViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico.png"];
UINavigationController *myNavigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:oFirstViewController]; 
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNavigationController1, myNavigationController2, myNavigationController3, myNavigationController4, nil];
```

This way, you have to add remaining view-controller to your tabbar controller.

Hope it will he helpful to you.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Comment: cha ching!  thanks bud ;-)  Thanks too to all who responded, appreciate it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your *tabBarController* contains only one *viewController*. So there will be only one *tabBarItem* available in *tabBarController*. As there is only one *viewController* available, that *tabBarItem* will be selected by default and you can't change the selection. So you don't feel like there is a button. But its there. You can set the *title* and *image* for the *viewController* and you will see the difference.

```
first.title = @"firstTab";
first.navigationItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"firstTab.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link that explain how to setup tabbar controller and navigation controller
[Link 1](http://amaniphone.blog.co.in/2010/11/13/tabbar-and-navifgation-in-iphonetabnav/)

Hope it helps you......

Answer (score 0):

```
[first.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"First" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] tag:0];
```